# P.O.R.T.A.L still credable or not

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, routers

https://github.com/grugq/portal

I know that this has not been developed for a while but was wondering if this still could be credible. Will getting the latest builds from tor be sufficient? And mimic a tor browser bundle. This does do bridges etc Any input would be great.

Answer (score 1):

"PORTAL" is what is termed an ["Isolating Proxy"](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TorifyHOWTO/IsolatingProxy). The concept is still valid and has definite advantages and "PORTAL" has been one of the best attempts to implement it, by actually offering access to Tor's `SOCKSPort` and not just forcing "Transparent Proxying". Fetching the latest updates for the software, and keeping the software up to date, is important, but the idea and the design is sound.

It would handle bridges but that will involve some further software porting, cross-compiling obfs4proxy for Linux on MIPS or whatever your architecture is.

Don't "mimic" Tor Browser, use actual Tor Browser on your client. It can be configured to use an Isolating Proxy.